# Select Item number from Sql Table

Tags: sql

I I have Two tables in sql

```
1.inventtable(itemnumber)
2.etext(itemnumber,Rkey,Rval,Lang,id,text)
```

I want to select the Itemnumber from inventtable where thw itemnumber same as in etext table and the itemnumber in etext table contain Rkey=1,rval=1,id=2).How to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select i.itemnumber
from inventtable i 
join etext e on i.itemnumber = e.itemnumber
where e.Rkey = 1 and e.rval =1 and e.id =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.itemnumber 
from inventtable i inner join etext e     
on i.itemnumber = e.itemnumber
where e.Rkey = 1 
and e.rval =1 
and e.id =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select itemnumber From  inventtable
Where inventtable in (Select itemnumber From  etext Where  Rkey=1 AND rval=1  AND id=2 )
```